# How can I disable or avoid Arrow Traps?

Tags: spelunky-hd

Arrow Traps are basically huge jerks. I'm able to activate their one shot by chucking a rock or other throwable item in front of them, and a bomb will destroy it. However there are times when I don't have access to a throwable item, and I'd prefer to avoid using bombs for disabling arrow traps. As far as I can tell there doesn't seem to be any way to avoid getting hit, but I could just be too slow.

In what ways can I either disable or avoid an arrow trap?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are the ways to bypass arrow traps:

- Throw/drop an item in front of the trap. Rocks, arrows, skulls and pots all work. So do weapons and other carriable items.
- Dead or alive bodies (damsels, cavemen, etc) will soak up the arrow for you - even if you're carrying them, regardless of which direction you are facing.
- Throw a mystery box or a supply crate in front of the trap. The arrow will open the box and release the item.
- Whip a wearable item to move it forward in front of the trap.
- Blow up the trap with a bomb. Watch out for the arrow, as this will not be destroyed and can sometimes fly up into the air.
- Destroy the trap with a mattock.
- Throw a rope down in front of the trap. If you crouch next to a ledge and use a rope it will go downwards.
- You can pick up critters (rat, frog, penguin, cricket) and drop them down in front of the arrow trap to set it off. Critters you are carrying will also soak up arrows, like bodies.
- You can hit an arrow with your whip as long as there is at least two spaces between you and the trap.
- It is possible to trigger an arrow trap but avoid the arrow if you are falling fast enough and there are enough spaces between you and the trap. Be careful, however, as the arrow can ricochet off walls and spear you anyway.

You will always begin the game next to a throwable item. Pick it up and carry it with you to disable any arrow traps you come across. Try to find a throwable item to carry to the next level with you as well.

If you have a dead body, or you find a critter, carry that with you to soak up any arrows. Do not carry stunned enemies as they will revive and attack you after a set period. Damsels only have 3 HP, so watch how much you damage them.

Answer (score 3):

Basically what you said - destroying them with bombs (or possibly a pickax) or throwing *something* in front of them - enemies, treasure, the girl, any item you hold in your hands. Other than that, you will have to either suck it up and throw *yourself* in front of it, or bypass it entirely by finding a different route or dropping down far enough in front of it.

Answer (score 2):

Another advanced trick is to jump and whip the arrow out of the air.

This YouTube video shows you some examples of the trick.